# WP AND LARAVEL get all pages connected by ID, polylang

Tags: laravel, wordpress, polylang

Friends,

I wanna find dynamic solution to find connected post's by polylang, because I need display page when current page ID is similar to page ID

Now I have this solution and its working by maybe you know more dynamic solution

```
@if(get_queried_object_id() == 38 /*EN*/ || get_queried_object_id() == 560 /*RU*/ || get_queried_object_id() == 651 /*LT*/ )
    @include('pages.contacts')
@endif
```

I wanna change this code to:

```
    // But I don't know how to get $contact_pages_ids;
    $contact_pages_ids = getConnectedPagesByLanguage(38); // return array(38, 560, 651); 
    // I need get array of IDS by first ID - 38, connected by language, plugin polylang
    @if(in_array(get_queried_object_id(), $contact_pages_ids))
        @include('pages.contacts')
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```php
$translations = $GLOBALS["polylang"]->model->post->get_translations($post->ID);
```

`$translations` contains an array with all translations of the post.